# Call intent on Recycler View

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

this is my **Recycler Adapter**.i want make a **call** when clicking call button. i don't know what to do.
please help me 
i added call button on holder. and after that i don't know anything.
this application making for blood bank in my locality.
so please help me immediately.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.Index;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;

public class NoteAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> {

    ListActivity listActivity;
    Context context;
    public NoteAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options) {
        super (options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Note model) {
        holder.name.setText (model.getName ());
        holder.place.setText (model.getPlace ());
        holder.location.setText (model.getMuncipality ());
        holder.blood.setText (model.getBloodgroup ());
        holder.number.setText (model.getNumber ());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.item_view,parent,false);
        return new NoteHolder (view);
    }

    static class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ListActivity listActivity;
        Context context;
        TextView name;
        TextView place;
        TextView blood;
        TextView location;
        TextView number;
        Button call;

        public NoteHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            name=itemView.findViewById (R.id.Name);
            place=itemView.findViewById (R.id.Place);
            blood=itemView.findViewById (R.id.Blood_group);
            location=itemView.findViewById (R.id.Muncipality);
            number=itemView.findViewById (R.id.mobileNumber);
            call=itemView.findViewById (R.id.call);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried or what you have found that could help you? "I don't know what to do" is not helpful. In addition, saying "so please help me immediately." is not a good way to ask for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also directly pass the number like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + model.getNumber());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to pass Context into your adapter.

```
Context context;
public NoteAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options,Context ctx) {
    super (options);
    content = ctx
}
```

after that, you can call your Intent using context.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Pass You TelePhone Number));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Your final code look like this.

```
public class NoteAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> {

    ListActivity listActivity;
    Context context;
    public NoteAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options,Context ctx) {
        super (options);
        content = ctx
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Note model) {
        holder.name.setText (model.getName ());
        holder.place.setText (model.getPlace ());
        holder.location.setText (model.getMuncipality ());
        holder.blood.setText (model.getBloodgroup ());
        holder.number.setText (model.getNumber ());
        holder.call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Pass You TelePhone Number));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } 
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.item_view,parent,false);
        return new NoteHolder (view);
    }

    static class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ListActivity listActivity;
        Context context;
        TextView name;
        TextView place;
        TextView blood;
        TextView location;
        TextView number;
        Button call;

        public NoteHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            name=itemView.findViewById (R.id.Name);
            place=itemView.findViewById (R.id.Place);
            blood=itemView.findViewById (R.id.Blood_group);
            location=itemView.findViewById (R.id.Muncipality);
            number=itemView.findViewById (R.id.mobileNumber);
            call=itemView.findViewById (R.id.call);

        }

    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the relevant permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: when i doing this method ``` adapter =new NoteAdapter(options)```
Goes error

Comment: You need to pass context when you init Adapter. Like this "adapter =new NoteAdapter(options,context)".